# any practical way to set-up OOO via file?

Tags: powershell, outlook

Is there a way to switch-on Out of Office on MS Outlook externally? I'm looking something like .ICS files that adds calendar item when a user executes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Exchange Admin you can set this up like this in PowerShell:

```
$username = "email@domain.com"
$starttime = "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"
$endtime = "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"
$msg_internal = "Internal out of office message"
$msg_external = "External out of office message"

# Enable automatic replies
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity $username -AutoReplyState Scheduled -StartTime $starttime -EndTime $endtime -InternalMessage $msg_internal -ExternalMessage $msg_external
```

Unfortunately, setting up an Out of Office (OOO) message in MS Outlook using an .ics file is not directly possible. You can create an event in your calendar for the period you will be out of office and then manually turn on the automatic replies feature in Outlook.

- Create a new calendar event for your time out of office.
- Save the event as an .ics file.
- Import the .ics file into your Outlook calendar.
- Manually turn on automatic replies in Outlook.